# UITableView Won't stop scrolling?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am building a feed comprised of `UITableViewController` + `NSFetchedResultsController`.

Each cell of the table view displays an image. The feed is configured to show images that have not been seen by the user, i.e. `seen == 0`

I would like to mark each cell as "seen" after the user has seen it. Naturally, I am doing this at:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    Item *item = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [[ItemStore sharedInstance] seenItem:item];
}
```

I would also like my feed to clean up rows once they have been marked seen. I have implemented the following:

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

    switch(type) {

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
```

**I am currently seeing a bug where if the user scrolls once, the table will keep scrolling infinitely to the next row. I realized that `tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` will force the table to scroll 1 forward. As a result, the row that has been past will be marked seen, deleted from the table and the table will scroll down 1 row again.**

Are there anyway to work around this problem?

My ideal goal would be to keep 3-4 rows above the current row and only delete them once they are beyond that range. Of course, I would not want the scroll to scroll by itself due to the deletion.

FULL SOURCE:

```
# pragma mark - NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate

- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
           atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {

    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex]
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex]
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    Item *item = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (item.seen) {
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

    switch(type) {

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

    }
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: did you try `[tableview beginUpdates] & [tableView endUpdates]` after insertrowAtIndex?

Comment: yup. why does that matter

Comment: If you know the number of cells deleted above and you get to know exactly when the delete occurs maybe you can look into modifying the tableView/scrollview contentOffset. Like doing the opposite from what one do for explicit *infinite* scroll...

Comment: @epatel i will consider that when I have exhausted everything lol. Yeah it should work in theory but then it might be a little hacky